# Using Dagger 2.11 with kotlin in android

Tags: android, gradle, kotlin, dagger-2

I'm trying to implement Dagger 2.11 in Android using kotlin. The first step is to add the Dagger (2.11) dependency to the Gradle build script. This is what I did:

```
apply plugin: 'kotlin-kapt'
...

dependencies {
    // Dagger core
    compile 'com.google.dagger:dagger:2.11'
    kapt 'com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:2.11'
    // Dagger Android
    compile 'com.google.dagger:dagger-android-support:2.11'
    kapt 'com.google.dagger:dagger-android-processor:2.11'
    ...
```

This is supposed to work, but when I try to sync I get this error:
`Error:Conflict with dependency 'com.google.code.findbugs:jsr305' in project ':app'. Resolved versions for app (3.0.1) and test app (2.0.1) differ. See http://g.co/androidstudio/app-test-app-conflict for details.`

Does anyone have any idea what causes this issue? Thanks

Comment: It worked perfectly. Thanks.

Comment: I don't think you want that second `kapt` entry.  It should work with just kapt for the dagger-compiler and compile (implementation) for dagger-android